# Android Google Auth Sign In handleSignInResult:false

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-signin, google-authenticator

I am developing the application where I am trying to login using Google. But getExtrasdata always returns null.

Here is what I have from log:

```
getSignInIntent = { act=com.google.android.gms.auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN cmp=com.rbsoftware.pfm.personalfinancemanager/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity (has extras) }

mGoogleApiClient=com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmg@1f595441

handleSignInResult:false

result=com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult@7d8c188

data=Intent { (has extras) }

getExtrasdata=Bundle[{googleSignInStatus=Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}}]
```

Everything should be ok in Developer Console.

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

```
package com.rbsoftware.pfm.personalfinancemanager;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // Button listeners
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);


        // [START configure_signin]
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // [END configure_signin]

        // [START build_client]
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        // [END build_client]

        // [Button]
        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {

            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {

                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // [START onActivityResult]
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
    // [END onActivityResult]

    // [START handleSignInResult]
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", acct.getDisplayName());
            intent.putExtra("id", acct.getId());
            intent.putExtra("email", acct.getEmail());
            intent.putExtra("photoURL", acct.getPhotoUrl());
            Log.d("USER Pic", acct.getPhotoUrl()+"");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
                   } else {
        }
    }
    // [END handleSignInResult]

    // [START signIn]
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    // [END signIn]



    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which PlayServices version do you use? We use 8.3 and have same problem.

Comment: same problem with 8.4 ... did you find a solution?

Comment: Check the OAuth client ID configuration for your project? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html

Answer (score 4):

The SHA1 fingerprint of keystore is corrupt. You have changed ~/.android/ ?, have reinstaled android studio?, you need regenerate the SHA1 key. Delete current key api from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and make a new key with SHA1 of new debug key store in ~/.android/debug.keystore (default password is empty).

Look this: https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-google-integration-and-login-tutorial/

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
```

Paste SHA1 into new key api for debug instances.

Remember: you neeed other fingerprint of production keystore.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be because you're not running the signed version of your app.
As Sudhanshu Gaur pointed out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808531/google-signin-handlesigninresult-returns-false-after-customizing-signin-butto), try first generate a signed apk using the same key you used to [create your json configuration file](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#prerequisites). Then install it on your device and see whether it works. The reason is Android Studio does not sign your apk when you click "run".
I was stuck on exactly the same problem and this fix worked fine for me.