# Some users facing issues with google login, and some can successfully login

Tags: android, google-signin

My app is live and I am pretty sure it does not issue a SHA key,
Sometimes users can't log into the app by Google but sometimes they can.

I'm sure it's not a developer issue right now because we didn't change anything in the login flow for a few months. It was working fine earlier, but since a few days ago it is not working.

We have already integrated crashlytics, I will give you idea what is happening with code.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result != null) {

                handleSignInResult(result);
            }
        } else {
          showToast(getBaseActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.something_went_wrong));
            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Here expected result code is -1 but i receive 0 which is RESULT_CANCELED which generally returns when SHA key is mismatched, but we didnt changed anything in our code which will cause this issue, also this is happening for few users, for signed app as well as debug app. FYI we use same keystore for debug and signed apk, so SHA is always same.

Comment: Application link?

Comment: you should add firebase analytics or roll your own solution to see the errors your users are facing, as it is you'll only get vague answers

Comment: Add Crashlytics to know what's the error you are facing so that you can have a clear idea of why it's happening.

Comment: Hey Santosh it would be better if you post the code.

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta what do you mean by cost?

Comment: hey its the typo. I was asking about posting your code.where you are getting the issue.

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta updated question with code

Comment: I think this is possible duplicate for this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075060/7352857 @santosh_gaikar

Comment: Thanks for the link but, issue received inside  if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
Here i am getting 0 instead of -1 @g.brahmaDatta

Comment: can anyone revert if they are able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Now, this seems to be fixed by Google, not facing this anymore.