# Google plus signs up but result shows failed in my android app

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-plus

I am trying to use google sign in in my android app. I have done every steps and enabled all permissions in the developers page and also used the code in the developers page to check. The app runs, my account shows up, asks for permission but when it comes back after authentication, the success result is false and so it is not signing in.

I used a log statement to check the sign in success and it shows false even before I click the sign in button and it stays the same even after I sign in.
Please tell me where I may be wrong or what should I do.

Comment: Try to follow the answer here in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808531/google-signin-handlesigninresult-returns-false-after-customizing-signin-butto). Put your google-service.json file inside your app folder and signed apk file then paste this apk file in your android mobile, from their open it not from android studio because it does not run the signed apk file on mobile device. Also check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008490/android-google-plus-sign-in-issue-handlesigninresult-returns-false), it might help you also.

Comment: I am getting a status code 10... I am trying to resolve it...and I have tried every other way but the Success result is always false and I cant retrieve information...

Answer (score 0):

Try to test it with signed apk. I think that is your problem.

Comment: Tried it sir. The problem is still there.